# google charts api - column chart - percentage above vertical bar along with normal values on left side of vaxis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google charts to generate a column chart as shown in this image:

```
http://postimg.org/image/mt7tzwwob/
```

Here, data will be like [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]

Here, I am getting values 1,2,3 on left left side of vaxis which is ok for me.

What I want extra is:  The percentages at the top of the vertical bar.

```
x+2x+3x = 100, means, x=16, 2x=33, 3x=50. So, 16% should be at top of vertical bar with value 1.
```

How can I get these percentages ?

Answer (score 0):

The ColumnChart's don't support adding labels like a percentage above the columns, but there is a work-around that involves using a ComboChart and a hidden line to add them in.  Here's some example code that adds in labels (you can replace the labels with percents in you want):

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

    data.addRows([
        ['Foo', 53, 'Foo text'],
        ['Bar', 71, 'Bar text'],
        ['Baz', 36, 'Baz text'],
        ['Cad', 42, 'Cad text'],
        ['Qud', 87, 'Qud text'],
        ['Pif', 64, 'Pif text']
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, 1, 2]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(view, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        series: {
            0: {
                type: 'bars'
            },
            1: {
                type: 'line',
                color: 'grey',
                lineWidth: 0,
                pointSize: 0,
                visibleInLegend: false
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            maxValue: 100
        }
    });
}
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/QjQNX/

This only works well for charts that have a single series of data (as the labels will be misaligned if there is more than one series).